# button doens't work ! I'm using .show(), hide(), toogle() and style.visibility

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Ive faced a problem which I have no idea the why ... so Im here..

http://videoarts.com.br/newSite/addAlbum.php

First, It has to select the "tipo". 
If is "foto" a form will show up. When the its filled in the "album nome" the "ok" button will show up and if clicked, will submit the form ! works fine !!!

But, if its selected "video" a new form will show up bellow the same foto's form with a new choice. If youtube is choosen, a link's field will show up. When filled with a right link, the ok button will show up, but **ITS NO POSSIBLE TO CLICK IT** !

If it selected video and then "arquivo" (its a portuguese word to file) the button also will show up and i have the same problem ... not clickable ...

I use Jquery hide, show and toogle to the forms and document.getelemen(buton).style.visibility to control the button ...

any idea ???

Comment: It's hard to debug this problem because of how much extra code is involved. If you could reproduce your problem in a [short, self contained correct example](http://sscce.org/), it would be much easier to help. Try re-creating your problem in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Style to

```
#contactButton input
{   z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: there's a div contactButton , which has the button. I put the z-index in this one, and worked fine !

Answer (score 1):

The div with an id of 'contactFone' is too long. So it's over lapping the the 'contactEmail' div.

You can set the z-index of the contactEmail div to be higher than the contactFone to fix it.

Put this in your css file

```
#contactEmail {
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: almost is ... if I do that, de div contactFone won't be clickable ... 
there's a div contactButton , which has the button. I put the z-index in this one, and worked fine !